# Is it possible to create an encrypted Excel file with the OpenXML SDK

Tags: excel, encryption, openxml, openxml-sdk, password-encryption

I'm working on a C# project that create, encrypt and send an excel file as an e-mail attachment.
I'm not looking to protect the excel, but encrypt it and set a password for opening it.
Is it even possible with the OpenXML SDK ?
I tried that, but I don't think this is for encrypting :

```
string hexConvertedPassword = HexPasswordConversion("Azerty123");
WorkbookProtection WorkbookProt = new WorkbookProtection()
{
    WorkbookPassword = hexConvertedPassword,
    RevisionsPassword = hexConvertedPassword,
    LockRevision = true,
    LockStructure = true,
    LockWindows = true,
};
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
workbook.Append(WorkbookProt);
```

I have already search in the documentation, but may have missed it.

I know some library can do it like devexpress, EasyXLS, Spire.Xls, etc, but those are very expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used FreeSpire.XLS to load my existing Excel file and add the encryption over it. Hopefully there is no limitation to load and save file with the free version.

Comment: I am considering on using FreeSprire.XLS only for the encryption functionality. Did you encounter any limitation?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to encrypt the content of DOCUMENT via reading cell by cell and generate a new **.xlsx** file.

```
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
    SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
    string text;
    foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
    {
        foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
        {
            // send to ecryption function.

            text = c.CellValue.Text;
            Console.Write(text + " ");
            
            
        }
    }
```

For more details visit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-parse-and-read-a-large-spreadsheet

Comment: Thanks for your answer that will work for the encryption, but not with the password, I forgot to say that I'm trying to make it so that when you open the excel file it asks for the password and decrypt the content.